# python / tk - affecting widget in other class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to create a ttk.notebook in python where the selection in one tab affects the selection of a widget in a separate tab.  Each tab is currently set up as a different class.  Is there a way to pass or call a function in one class(tab) and have it change the widget/call a function in the other class(tab)?

in short, i have two functions: lb1 and lb2 (for tk lisboxes).  Ideally, I would like the selection function on lb1 to call a function to populate a list in lb2.  Each are in different classes.

a general sample of what I am trying to do follows.

```
class One(ttk.Frame):
    ...
    lb1 = Listbox(listvariable = apps, height = 5)
    def lb2_lookup(self, *args):
        #this would somehow call a function to populate lb2
    self.lb1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.lb2_lookup)



class Two(ttk.Frame):
    lb2 = Listbox(listvariable = lb2apps, height = 5)
```

Thanks a bunch.  I apologize if the code sample makes no sense, but I believe it gets the general point across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that for one class to call a function in another, it simply needs to have a reference to that class, or a reference to some sort of controller class that has a reference to the other class.

```
class One(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, other_class):
        self.other_class = other_class
        ...
        self.lbl.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>`, self.other_class.lb2_lookup)

two = Two(...)
one = One(..., other_class = two)
```

Another way to accomplish the same thing is to have the class provide an interface, so that you can connect the classes after they are created:

```
class One(...):
    ...
    def set_target(self, other_class):
        self.other_class = other_class
class Two(...):
    ...
one = One(...)
two = Two(...)
one.set_target(two)
```

Finally, as written your code is tighly coupled. That means that even a small change in Two might mean you have to modify class One as well. That makes for code that is hard to maintain. You should create an interface that doesn't require one class to know much about the implementation of the other class.

Specifically, in your example you are setting up a binding to call lb2_lookup. But what if you change class Two and rename lb2 to lb3? Do you really want to have to also modify One? Better to create a function in Two that doesn't directly relate to a widget. For example:

```
class One(...):
    ...
    self.lb1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.other_class.lookup)
```

With that, you are now free to reimplement `Two` however you want. The only requirement is that you keep a method named `lookup`. However, exactly what `lookup` does can change as long as it works the same way.

So, for example, right now `lookup` could return the value from a widget named `lb2`, but later it could look up data from a widget named `foobar`.  No matter what `lookup` does, as long as it works in the same way (takes the same arguments, returns the same type of result), you won't have to modify `One` whenever you change `Two`.